# Issue when passing MySQL LONGTEXT as JSON in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have MySQL table called articles for my news website. When i tried to get all data from that table using PHP, I can pass all data in JSON but `article_text`. This is what i did,

(This is just for test)

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM articles");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $arr = array("id"=>$row["article_id"],
                     "title"=>$row["title"],
                     "image"=>$row["image"],
                     "text"=>$row["article_text"]);
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

This is not returning anything. So i removed `"text"=>$row["article_text"]` from array, It worked. All the data returned as a JSON array. Is this a data type issue or my coding issue. How can i solve this ?. Thank you.

Comment: What is the value of article_text that is giving you problems? It is possible there is a character or more in it causing the json encoding to fail. See also http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: @systematical: Thank you for comment. Its a large text. It contains the article body. I'll check that reference.

Comment: json_last_error() shows 5. I figured it out. I think my text contains a malformed character. Thank you

Comment: You may have things like quotations, or other special characters in there.  As a last resort you could base64_encode it in php and then decode it on the javascript end.  Depending on how many times you need to do that it might take some performance out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the bitmask options for json_encode.

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

These options are explained here:
http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

You are likely looking for something like JSON_HEX_QUOT, but play around with them. Example:

```
$string = json_encode($array, JSON_HEX_QUOT);
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `UTF8` bitmask options to your `json_encode` and it should resolve the issue. Like this:

```
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE | JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE);
```

I ran into the same problem yesterday and was looking all over the internet to resolve it, when I came across someone with similar problem who said he resolved it by adding the `UTF8` character set just below his select query, I tried it, but he wasn't clear with sharing his solution or how he did it. So when I saw the comment to this question, I used the links to refer to php manuals on json ecode and saw the `UTF8` `json_encode` bitmask options, I felt it might be the solution and it worked!

You can also add more json encode bitmask options for a more clean json file. Like:

```
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE | JSON_INVALID_UTF8_SUBSTITUTE | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Hope this will help anyone facing this challenge.